# Why does my text not showing up after a post request - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently making a basic twitter clone. Everything went perfect before my text started not showing up when I made a post request.
What would be the problem?
My code:

app.js:

```
var     express     = require("express"),
        mongoose    = require("mongoose"),
        bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
        ejs         = require("ejs");

var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/twitter_clone", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => console.log("CONNECTED TO DB"))
.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// MONGODB TWEETS SCHEMA

var tweetsSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String
})
var Tweets = mongoose.model("Tweets", tweetsSchema);

//================
//RESTFUL ROUTES
//================

// INDEX ROUTES

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    Tweets.find({}, function(err, allTweets){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("home", {newtweet:allTweets});
        }
    })
})
app.get("/explore", function(req, res){
    res.render("explore");
})
app.get("/notifications", function(req, res){
    res.render("notifications");
})
app.get("/messages", function(req, res){
    res.render("messages");
})
app.get("/bookmarks", function(req, res){
    res.render("bookmarks");
})
app.get("/lists", function(req, res){
    res.render("lists");
})
app.get("/profile", function(req, res){
    res.render("profile");
})
app.get("/more", function(req, res){
    res.render("more");
})

// NEW ROUTES

app.get("/tweet/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("new");
})


// POST

app.post("/posttweet", function(req, res){
    var text = req.body.text;
    var newtweet = {text: text};
    Tweets.create(newtweet, function(err, newTweet){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    })
})
//DELETE
app.get("/delete/:id", function(req,res){
    mongoose.model("Tweets").remove({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, delData){
        res.redirect("/");
    })
})
app.listen(5000, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on port 5000");
})
```

---

home.ejs:

```
<form action="/tweet/new">
    <input class="bluebutton" type="submit" value="Tweet" />
</form>
<div class="tweets">
    <% newtweet.forEach(function(newtweet){ %>
        <div class="showtweets">
            <p class="tweetcontent">
                <%= newtweet.text %>
            </p>
        </div>
    <% }) %>
</div>
```

---

I asked a similar question before and I found a solution and it worked well for a while, but I made some changes and now it's not working poroperly.

Comment: Where in home.ejs do you make a post request? The form sends a request to /tweet/new with a GET method.

Comment: It works the same as a href="/tweet/new"
Just a link to the form page

Answer (score 0):

Create a form that sends a post request to "/posttweet":

```
<form action="/posttweet" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Tweet" />
</form>
```

This should make the right request to your single post route.

Edit
Tip: Make sure to send back some response from your handlers, even if its an error, otherwise your server will just hang.

Comment: I already created the form and it only gives back the id

Comment: @MrHulky How does that form look like?